# The archive: /AppsMobile/native/internal_tmp which is referenced by the classpath, does not exist

Tags: java, mobile, codenameone

When I try to run my mobile application on simulator in codenameone, I am getting the above error. Could you please provide me a solution.

Comment: Please post your error in the question. So that it will be easy to analyze.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its a directory, just create that directory and all should be fine.

The build script should automatically create that archive. Which IDE are you using?

Comment: Thank you for the solution. I am using Spring tool suite. When I try to import source code from git repository to my workspace in STS, I arise with this problem.